# value from ajax request not available

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval

i have a function inside my document.onready, that fires an ajax request and sets the value of a hidden input on my page. i have it set up this way as what i want happening is needed on every page, so it's not a value that i could return with my controller.

followed by that, i have a setInterval, every 10 seconds that checks the value of this hidden input, makes an ajax request to see if the value has changed, and if so, displays a message on the screen using Toastr (but it could be an alert or whatever).

the problem is that it's displaying the message when it sets the value of the hidden input the first time around, and i think it is because this is an ajax request, and by the time setinterval is called, the value is not yet available, so it takes it as 0 the first time around, and later as to whatever it should have been, and takes this as a change.

is there a work around for this? the code is as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        getStartingMissedJobs(); // Sets the value of the hidden input
        var startingMissedJobs = $('#missedJobs').val(); // store that value in a variable

        setInterval(function () {
// here i set the variable to the new value, if it 's changed or keep it..see below
            startingMissedJobs = checkIfNewExpiredJobs(startingMissedJobs);
        }, 10000);
    });
```

functions:

```
    var getStartingMissedJobs = function() {
        var localUrl = 'http://mylink.com';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: localUrl + "/actionurl",
            data: {},
            success: function(response) {
                var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
                $('#missedJobs').val(parsedResponse[0]);
             },
             error: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                },
            dataType: 'html',
         });
    };
    var checkIfNewExpiredJobs = function(startingMissedJobs) {
        getExpiredJobs();
        var missedJobs = $('#missedJobs').val();
        if (missedJobs > startingMissedJobs) {
            missedJob();
            return missedJobs;
        }
        return startingMissedJobs;
    };

    $(function() {
        $('.nav-user li').hover(function(){
              $(this).addClass("open");
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("open");
        });
    });
});

    var getExpiredJobs = function() {
        var serverUrl = 'http://contractor.hvac4.us/';
        var localUrl = 'http://fcarranza.contractor.sfdev01.com/';
        var missedJobs; 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: localUrl + "dispatch/newmissed",
            data: {},
            success: function(response) {
                var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
                missedJobs = parsedResponse[0];
                $('#missedJobs').val(missedJobs);
             },
             error: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            dataType: 'html',
         });
        return missedJobs;
    };
```

thank you,

fer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `getStartingMissedJobs` retrieves and sets the value of the `missedJobs` input asynchronously to the rest of your code. That means the line:

```
var startingMissedJobs = $('#missedJobs').val();
```

will get evaluated whilst the request is in progress, so unlikely to get the proper value.

One way to solve this would be to pass to `getStartingMissedJobs` a callback function that should be called when the request has completed.

That function can then be used to create the interval for subsequent checks with the initial value already obtained.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getStartingMissedJobs(function() {
        var startingMissedJobs = $('#missedJobs').val();
        setInterval(function () {
            startingMissedJobs = checkIfNewExpiredJobs(startingMissedJobs);
        }, 10000);
    });
});


var getStartingMissedJobs = function(callback) {
    ....
    ....
    $.ajax({
        ....
        success: function(response) {
            var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
            $('#missedJobs').val(parsedResponse[0]);
            callback();
         },
         error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            callback();
         },
         ....
```

Comment: i wanted to give you a rating up but i don't have the points yet! this worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: i clicked on the check button, i think that's it??